# OpenCV inclusion error of core_c.h

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have downloaded opencv with svn and used cmake to compile it. I have
followed [this nice
guide](http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/).

I have created my first project with basic inclusion:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

But when I try to compile I get:

```
C:\Progam Files\OpenCV\include\opencv\cv.h(63): fatal error
"opencv2/core/core_c.h" no such file or directory
```

How Can I solve this? Should I explicit set some custom include dir?  IT
pretty strange because Cmake should have done all configuration...

I am on **Visual Studio 2010** with **Windows Vista**

On the project properties I have added `"C:\Progam Files\OpenCV\include"` as
include directories

Note in `configuration properties->C/C++->Aditional include directories` there
is already: `C:\Progam Files\OpenCV\include`

### Edit

It turns out cmake made the VC project with bad inclusion directory, I had to
manually set all the

```
C:\Progam Files\OpenCV\modules/*/include
```

directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you added `include` directory to `include directories` option in VS (Configuration properties->C/C++->Aditional include directories).

Comment: I have added it on Propriety -> VC++ Directory -> include directory, still no luck :(

Comment: ok in Aditional include directories there is alredy `C:\Progam Files\OpenCV\include` :(

Comment: @yes123 Does this folder contains file opencv2/core/core_c.h?

Comment: yes that folder contains `opencv\cv.h` **but not** `opencv2/core/core_c.h`

Comment: Wait maybe i got the problem, in the Aditional include directories there are lot of paths that doens't exists, they are like: "C:\Program Files\myProjectName\Files\OpenCV\modules\" but they should be "C:\Program Files\OpenCV\modules\etc"

Comment: @yes123 delete other include directories and add only `include` folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13566/discussion-between-astor-and-yes123)

Comment: I have added manually "C:\Progam Files\OpenCV\modules/*/include" and now it's working.. it must be cmake error